# Get number of words from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `z_words`, and `z_words_products`. You can see bellow the structure of these tables.

In the `z_words_products` table could be the same values for:

`wordId`,`smaId`,`productId`,`siteId` and the `type` value is different.

What I want to achive, to get 1 number, a count. I want to know, how many words in my table, but one word counts one in a product, even, if it occures twice in one product.

For example:

```
SELECT `zw`.`word`, `zwp`.`smaId`, COUNT(*) AS `cnt` 
FROM `z_words` `zw`
INNER JOIN `z_words_products` `zwp` ON `zwp`.`wordId` = `zw`.`id`
WHERE `zwp`.`siteId` = 0 
AND `zwp`.`smaId` = 1 
GROUP BY `zw`.`word`, `zwp`.`smaId`
```

**Output**

```
+--------------+-------+-----+
|     word     | smaId | cnt |
+--------------+-------+-----+
| 8100         |     1 |   1 |
| 8102wlci     |     1 |   1 |
| 8104wlmi     |     1 |   1 |
| Acer         |     1 |   2 |
| unknown      |     1 |   1 |
+--------------+-------+-----+
```

As you see, Acer occures twince, because it is in with type `A` and type `B`, but I at the final result it should count as 1.

So my final query result should be 5, not 6. Of course, there are thousends of products in my table.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(cnt) FROM (
   SELECT `zw`.`id` AS `cnt` 
   FROM `z_words` `zw`
   INNER JOIN `z_words_products` `zwp` ON `zwp`.`wordId` = `zw`.`id`
   WHERE `zwp`.`siteId` = 0 
   AND `zwp`.`smaId` = 1
   GROUP BY `zw`.`word`, `zwp`.`smaId`) 
 AS xxx
```

It works, gives me back the right result. My problem is, when I run it on all the products it tooks 6-7 minuites.

Is there another way to get the results faster?

In the `z_words_products` are 6 147 059 records, in the `z_words` table are 367 771

Eplain of the query:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |   table    |  type  |                 possible_keys                 |     key      | key_len |          ref           | rows |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | \N                                            | \N           | \N      | \N                     |   14 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | zwp        | ref    | PRIMARY,siteId_smaId,wordId,wordId_2,wordId_3 | siteId_smaId | 8       | const,const            |   14 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | zw         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY      | 4       | partcollect.zwp.wordId |    1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**The tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `z_words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `translated` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transTry` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `word` (`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=526303 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `z_words_products` (
  `wordId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `smaId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('word','compatible','partNumber','tag','model') NOT NULL,
  `siteId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`wordId`,`smaId`,`productId`,`type`,`siteId`),
  KEY `siteId_smaId` (`siteId`,`smaId`),
  KEY `wordId` (`wordId`,`productId`),
  KEY `wordId_2` (`wordId`,`order`),
  KEY `wordId_3` (`wordId`),
  KEY `wordId_4` (`productId`,`order`),
  CONSTRAINT `z_words_products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`wordId`) REFERENCES `z_words` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to write a query using `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT...)` on the `z_words_products` table over the appropriate columns, omitting the `type` column.

It's hard to tell exactly how you want to define the count, but based on your two example queries it appears you want to count distinct values of `wordId` for a given `(sitId,smaId)` pair.

If that assumption is correct, this query should work for you:

```
SELECT count(distinct `zwp`.`wordId`)
FROM `z_words_products` `zwp`
WHERE `zwp`.`siteId` = 0 
AND `zwp`.`smaId` = 1;
```

Comment: You are totally right. I do not know, what I did yesterday. I think I was on a trip in my brain when I wrote this question :))) And the joke is that I do not need the count of the words. I am working on a cosin similarity method, and I need documents, not words. Anyway, thank you to englightened, silly me.